# Setting focus to maximize button

Tags: java, focus, swt

In SWT can I set focus to the maximize button of a view?
More concretely I want to set a tablist for a composite with `setTabList()` method, but I can't refer to the maximize button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the controls in a `setTabList()` call must be direct children of the `Composite`. Since the maximize button belongs to a `ToolBar` outside of the view you can't use it in the tab list.